# vagrant network bridge using public static ip

Tags: networking, bridge, vagrant

I am using vagrant 2.2.3 version and I want to configure bridge network using static ip address. My code is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", auto_config: false  
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "ifconfig eth1 192.168.10.71 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
```

I want to use 192.168.1.32 as the IP.

Answer (score 1):

From the [vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html), I believe the following is what you are looking for. Add the below to your Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.32"
```